# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't work after update

Tags: unity, 12.10

12.10 doesn't work after a partial distribution update. I had some trouble before I began the update, and the Partial Update thingy appeared. It took about 6 hours to update/upgrade, don't know why.
After the update, I restarted the laptop and nautilus doesn't appear nor does Unity.
I can't switch to Gnome or anything else to try and fix it. The resolution is weird (doesn't fill out the right side of the screen). I'm almost sure it's Compiz who's the sinner (or me.) but I need help to get everything working again.
Internet connections is fine. I have tried
    sudo apt-get install -f
and
    sudo apt-get upgrade
and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your GPU drivers are interfering; or that your hw isn't 3d-capable.
Please post the result of the following command:

```
`$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`
```

A. If you're using nVidia drivers:
Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

```
`$sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
`$sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-experimental-304)
```

Or just open Synaptic and search for nvidia, delete everything that you see now.

Reboot the system. See if everything's working. Run this command to check if Unity-3D will work:

`$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`

Reboot again. Reinstall latest nVidia drivers:

`$sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

B. If using AMD/ATI GPU drivers:
Run the following command to remove them, and reboot:

```
`$sudo apt-get purge fglrx`
```

Don't reinstall them as ATI cards currently don't support Unity-3D.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar troubles after upgrade to 12.10.
The problem was that my graphics driver disappear after upgrade.
For my nvidia graphics card works this command:

```
apt-get install nvidia-current
```

find your graphics driver command for installation and try it out.

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Try restore option in grub menu at startup-just enable networking and fix broken packages to finish upgrade. Or else

- sudo apt-get install aptitude && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
- sudo apt-get update -f && sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the fglrx drivers (for ati cards)? In that case this is a known bug. Please go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661 and report that it affects you too (the option is near the top of the page).

You can remove the fglrx drivers and revert to the open source drivers (which should work) by following the instructions on http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx